# Having trouble with the format of a custom action in WIX

Tags: wix, appcmd

I am trying to configure APICGIRestriction using APPCMD in WIX.

The compiler throws an error saying "INvalid Format". When I try this command on the server directly, it works fine.

Any ideas?

I am using WIX 3.5 version. Also, I couldn't figure out how to get the property reference for NETFRAMEWORK40INSTALLROOTDIR either.

Thanks
Sunanda

Comment: some example code would help..

Answer (score 1):

It's probably because of the square brackets. Try the following - note the '**[[]**' to escape the square bracket.

```
<CustomAction Id="ConfigureFastCGI" Execute="deferred" Impersonate="no" Return="check" Directory="TARGETDIR"
                  ExeCommand="[System64Folder]inetsrv\appcmd set config /section:system.webServer/fastCgi &quot;/+[\[]fullPath='[Dir_MapServerGDALX64]bin\mapserv.exe'[\]]&quot; " />
```